How to call an object's IUnknown::QueryInterface on Mac VBA
IUnknown::QueryInterface is called under the hood when you do something like
Dim animal As IAnimal
Set animal = New Dog 'Dog.QueryInterface(IID_IAnimal) called under the hood

However sometimes you want to invoke it manually, perhaps because you're after an interface that you know exists, and you have the IID of, but is not exposed for you to create a variable of that type - e.g. IDispatch. Then you may do the following instead:
Dim dog As New Dog
Dim dogIDispatch As IUnknown

'read IUnknown::QI from vtable
Dim pDogQI As LongPtr
pDogQI = MemLongPtr(MemLongPtr(ObjPtr(dog))) 

'invoke QI manually using the vtable fn and objptr(dog)
Set dogIDispatch = DispCallFuncWrapper(pDogQI, ObjPtr(dog), IID_IDispatch) 

DispCallFunc is not available on Mac, so is there any other way to query an object for an interface by guid on Mac? Or more generally to StdCall a function pointer with some args?
Additional context/what I've tried
I am trying to get the IConnectionPoint interface without referencing a non-standard typelib (I don't want to impose a dll dependency). I also need to invoke its members but that's another problem.
My current and only line of thinking is to compile DispCallFunc from source code in Wine (open-source c code for lots of useful windows DLLs), but adapt it so it works as a class method (and just ignores the first argument). Then create a dummy VBA object with a stub member matching the DispCallFunc API. Finally inject the compiled c code as a hardcoded binary array and mark it executable, and then override the vtable entry of the stub function to point to the injected code instead. Then calling DummyObject.DispCallFunc(args) would invoke the injected machine code. This wouldn't work on 64 bit as I believe simple vtable patching no longer works.
